# Регулярные выражения. Только латинница и цифры в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

```
regexp.test(string)
```

Нужно проверить строку на полное совпадение с регулярным выражением (наличие в строке только латинницы и цифры одновременно).

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` - пробовал, оно проверяет как ИЛИ, а надо И.

Несколько примеров кейсов:
"1"
"q1"
"1q"
"q1q1"
"asdasdDASD2ewdasFwd3E"
"asdadsdasd234234"
"123q"
"1q2e3r1aAWwd23da1"
"d23erwry2367rtw7y8urj43ur2u920fjwheufds89sjk"
"qkwduiygfewr1627e81i02171tey18eu901ie09u8u8u88uu88uu000"

Comment: То есть вы хотите чтобы строка содержала одновременно латиницу и цифры? И добавьте пару кейсов для

Comment: `^(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: Да, одновременно только буквы и символы.
Добавил примеры кейсов

Comment: `^(?:[A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[A-Za-z]+)[\dA-Za-z]*$` попробуйте такой вариант с логическим или

Comment: Это работает. Большое спасибо, помогло. Я думал это можно как-то проще всё написать, но смотрю что тут никак походу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать одно из следующих выражений:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$
^(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$
^(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$
^(?:\d+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$
^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

*Подробности*

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` - после нуля и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно меньше, должна быть буква из набора ASCII
- `(?=.*?\d)` - после нуля и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно меньше, должна быть буква из набора ASCII
- `(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)` - после текущей позиции должно быть ноль и более цифр, сразу после которых идёт буква из набора ASCII, или ноль и более букв из набора ASCII, сразу после которых идёт цифра
- `(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)` - после текущей позиции должно быть ноль и более цифр, сразу после которых идёт буква из набора ASCII, или ноль и более нецифровых символов, сразу после которых идёт цифра
- `(?:\d+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+` / `([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - одна и более цифр, а потом буква из набора ASCII или ноль и более букв из набора ASCII, а потом цифра, после которых идёт одна и более цифр или букв из набора ASCII
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - одна и более цифр или букв из набора ASCII
- `$` - конец строки.